# Swift admob not showing even after interstitialWillPresentScreen

Tags: swift, admob

I don't know why but even after printing Admop interstitialWillPresentScreen, 
ad is not showing.

```
func interstitialWillPresentScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("Admop interstitialWillPresentScreen")
    }
```

appDelegate

```
 GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
```

ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-   3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.delegate=self
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

 }

func didSelectRowAt(indexPath:IndexPath){
     <-- I want to show ad when this function is called back from    table view. 
    if interstitial.isReady {
        print("Ad showing")
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
```

but I think the problem is that...
I don't have view from main.storyboard sth...
I generate all view from code in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

I guess...this is the reason...???

I don't find any error in code and because it comes to interstitialWillPresentScreen method...